# html video new tab option disabled

Tags: html, css

I added my bootstrap website for the video
but when I right click and tried to open new tab on this video, new tab option  disabled, any solution to enable this option??
Thanks

here the code

```
<video autoplay="" target="_blank" class="header-index__video" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""
                               src="assets/video/Home.mp4" style="width:100%"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no other choice but instead placing a thumbnail of the video, then wrap it with anchor tag with `href` value of the targeted video. It does exactly what you are expecting. Something like this:

```html
<a href="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
</a>
```